# Finding last row throws an object required error

Tags: excel, vba

What I am trying to do.

1. I highlight some text in an email then run my macro.
2. It 'copies' the highlighted text and stores it in variable strText.
3. Then it creates a file called Artwork List.xlsx if it does not exist and if it exists it opens it.
4. After that it copies the text into the file in column A row 1 if the lastrow is 1, and if not, it appends to lastrow + 1

My code throws

> 'Run-time error 424, Object required'

To narrow down, the error should be coming from:

```
lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

or anything related to this line.

```
Sub copyArts2File()
MsgBox "ok"
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim olInsp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim strText As String

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlBook As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object

Dim strTextArr As Variant

On Error Resume Next
'Get Outlook if it's running
Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

'Outlook wasn't running, so cancel
If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Outlook is not running so nothing can be selected!"
    GoTo lbl_Exit
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = OutApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
With OutMail
    Set olInsp = .GetInspector
    Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
    strText = wdDoc.Application.Selection.Range.Text
End With
'MsgBox strText

lbl_Exit:
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Set olInsp = Nothing
Set wdDoc = Nothing

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = False

FileName = "Artwork List.xlsx"
fileDoesExist = Dir("C:\Users\quaer\Desktop\DL Arts\" & FileName) > ""

' Check for existing file
If fileDoesExist Then
    ' Open Excel file
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\quaer\Desktop\DL Arts\" & FileName)
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets(1)
Else
    ' Add Excel file
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    With xlBook
        .SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\quaer\Desktop\DL Arts\" & FileName
    End With
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets(1)
End If

' Do stuff with Excel workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long
With xlApp
    With xlBook
        With xlSheet
        strTextArr = Split(strText, "Adding file")
        lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        MsgBox lastrow
        If lastrow = 1 Then

            For i = 1 To UBound(strTextArr)
                .Range("A" & i).Value = strTextArr(i)
            Next i

        Else
            For i = 1 To UBound(strTextArr)
                .Range("A" & (i + lastrow)).Value = strTextArr(i)
            Next i

        End If
        .Close SaveChanges:=True
        End With
    End With
End With
xlApp.Visible = True
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` to `lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` .. .you are missing a `.` should be `.Rows`

Comment: Looking at how You set xlSheet You don't need that
'With xlApp' and 'With xlBook' because it is already included in xlSheet.
Also here: '.Close SaveChanges:=True' You can't close xlSheet, but You can:
xlBook.Close SaveChanges:=True

Comment: Thanks  Mikku and Teamothy for coming back, unfortunately none of these solutions work. Anymore ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line, `lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`, with:

`lastrow = .Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

or

`lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count +1, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 0):

Jeeez this is crazy. I have found the problem finally and got a working code for anyone wanting similar usage. 1st off, I need to add the Microsoft excel add in. So in Outlook VBA, Tools -> references -> check Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library. This is to get rid of the 424 object required error, as I was trying to a call a excel built in method I guess. this is the line:

```
lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Pls note that I am calling this macro from Outlook.

After this I faced a couple of other issues. 
1. errors such as 424 run time, remote server machine does not exist or is not available.
first time running, it throws this error, 2nd time I click, the problem goes away. This is an issue with non specific use of the app, book and worksheet and so leaves VBA to assign on its own. Lesson learnt, be explicit about every thing.

2. leaves a copy of excel process even after program ends. This can be seen in task manager. This causes issues because then my excel file is linked to this process and not able to open without either read only or notify. Its locked with the process. So I cannot run again next time.

Anyway. Here is the final code. And I have also changed it to .Range instead of .Cells. I believe it does not matter if I used either but the key culprit is : xlSheet.Rows.Count. Instead of just Rows.Count, explicitly use xlSheet.Rows.Count.

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyArts2File()
MsgBox "ok"
Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object, olInsp As Object, wdDoc As Object
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application, xlBook As Excel.Workbook, xlSheet As Object
Dim strText As String
Dim strTextArr As Variant
Dim fName As String
Dim fileDoesExist As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long

On Error Resume Next
'Get Outlook if it's running
Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

'Outlook wasn't running, so cancel
If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Outlook is not running so nothing can be selected!"
    GoTo lbl_Exit
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = OutApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
With OutMail
    Set olInsp = .GetInspector
    Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
    strText = wdDoc.Application.Selection.Range.Text
End With
'MsgBox strText
'Close out all shit
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Set olInsp = Nothing
Set wdDoc = Nothing

lbl_Exit:
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Set olInsp = Nothing
Set wdDoc = Nothing

On Error Resume Next 'Create or use a Excel Application
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err.Number > 0 Then Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

xlApp.Visible = False
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

fName = "Artwork List.xlsx"
fileDoesExist = Dir("C:\Users\quaer\Desktop\DL Arts\" & fName) > ""

' Check for existing file
If fileDoesExist Then
    ' Open Excel file if present
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\quaer\Desktop\DL Arts\" & fName)
Else
    ' Add Excel file if not present
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    xlBook.SaveAs fileName:="C:\Users\quaer\Desktop\DL Arts\" & fName
End If
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)


' Do stuff with Excel workbook
strTextArr = Split(strText, "Adding file")
lastrow = xlSheet.Range("A" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If lastrow = 1 Then

    For i = 1 To UBound(strTextArr)
        xlSheet.Range("A" & i).Value = strTextArr(i)
    Next i

Else
    For i = 1 To UBound(strTextArr)
        xlSheet.Range("A" & (i + lastrow)).Value = strTextArr(i)
    Next i

End If


xlBook.SaveAs fileName:="C:\Users\quaer\Desktop\DL Arts\" & fName, AccessMode:=xlExclusive, ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges
xlBook.Close (True)

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlSheet = Nothing
xlApp.Visible = True
xlApp.Quit

Set xlApp = Nothing

MsgBox "Done!"
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help and suggestions nonetheless.